# whm cpanel installation process was unable to synchronize cPanel & WHM

Tags: cpanel, whm

I am trying to install the whm cpanel in centos 7.

I ran the following command to stop the firewall service

```
systemctl stop firewalld.service
systemctl disable firewalld.service
```

after that I downloaded the latest bash script and ran it

```
wget https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest
sudo bash latest
```

but i am getting the following error.

```
file /usr/bin/my_print_defaults conflicts between attempted installs of MySQL56-server-5.6.33-1.cp1156.x86_64 and cpanel-mysql-5.1.73-1.cp1156.x86_64 [2016-09-25 04:46:50 +0530]   
file /usr/bin/mysql_config conflicts between attempted installs of MySQL56-devel-5.6.33-1.cp1156.x86_64 and cpanel-mysql-5.1.73-1.cp1156.x86_64[2016-09-25 04:46:50 +0530]  
file /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/analog from install of cpanel-analog-6.0-2.cp1136.x86_64 conflicts with file from package anaconda-core-21.48.22.56-5.el7.centos.1.x86_64
[2016-09-25 04:46:50 +0530]   see https://go.cpanel.net/rpmcheckfailed for more information
2016-09-25 04:46:50  830 (DEBUG):   The installation process detected a failed synchronization. The system will reattempt the synchronization with the updatenow.static file...
2016-09-25 04:46:50  836 (FATAL): The installation process was unable to synchronize cPanel & WHM. Verify that your network can connect to httpupdate.cpanel.net and rerun the installer.
```

Removing /root/installer.lock.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql service is already installed on your server and due to that you are facing this issues while installing cPanel on your server. Try to remove all mysql packages which is installed on your server and then install cPanel on your server.